# Using associative array values from within the same array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm trying to access an associative array's key and value from within the same array. If I have 3 pairs in my array. Can I use the value of let's say the values of `something` and `other` within the third one `another`?

```
$gar = array("something" => "something value", 
             "other" => "other value", 
             "another" => something . other 
       );
```

The idea is that another's value will be "something valueother value".

Is this possible? Is there a way to accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be fine if you use it on multiple lines like this:

```
$gar = array();
$gar["something"] = "something value";
$gar["other"] = "other value";
$gar["another"] = $gar["something"].$gar["other"];
```

You could even put the above sequence in a loop then.

Comment: I went for this, just because it's a little cleaner looking, although both work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

how about just something like this

```
$gar = array("something" => "something value", 
         "other" => "other value"
   );

$gar["another"] = $gar["something"] . $gar["other"];
```

Answer (score 0):

my question speaks about the analogous problem too. Hope that helps! :)
[PHP - Accessing array element within the same array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617139/php-accessing-array-element-within-the-same-array)