# PHP - Accessing array element within the same array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Having an [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), I want to call a value giving a key within the same array!
In my following example, I have tried to call a particular value giving the key `'default'` within the same array, but without success! Is it possible to do that in [PHP](http://www.php.net/)? Here is my array:

```
$inc_folders = array(
         'default' => "def_folder",
         'file'     => $inc_folders['default'] . "/textfile.txt" 
    );
```

calling the value in `$inc_folders['file']`, I would want the result be the following: `"def_folder/textfile.txt"`; but I obtain an error!

Please, can you help me to resolve that?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign it to a variable first; like so:

```
$folder = "def_folder";
$inc_folders = array(
    'default' => $folder,
    'file'     => $folder . "/textfile.txt" 
);
```

Or alternatively, build the array in two steps:

```
$inc_folders = array(
    'default' => "def_folder"
);

$inc_folders['file'] = $inc_folders['default'] . "/textfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 1):

like this

```
$inc_folders = array(
    'default' => "def_folder"
);

$inc_folders['file']= $inc_folders['default'] . "/textfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, just not how you are currently trying:

```
$inc_folders['default'] = "def_folder";
$inc_folders['file']    = $inc_folders['default'] . "/textfile.txt";
```